# Is 「悪く言うと」 used in a positive sense here?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Source: https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/6741640.html

> しかも彼女は私に嫌な感情を持っていないので（私は、よく「情が深い」と言われるタイプで、（**悪く言うと**八方美人なのですが）周囲の人を大切にするので、あまり嫌な感情は持たれません。）距離が取れません。

Is the poster here using 「悪く言うと」in a positive sense here?

OR

Is「八方美人」 used as a negative word and 「悪く言うと」shows the negative sense/meaning?

Comment: Isn't 八方美人 almost always negative when describing someone's personality? I don't think it would be necessary to spell it out as negative for that to be implied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although there is a literal definition of 八方美人 [どこから見ても欠点のない美人 (from 三省堂スーパー大辞林)  'perfectly beautiful from all angles'], this phrase is usually used in an idiomatic way, with a negative connotation. It's a pejorative term describing someone who is insincere because they pretend they are everyone's friend and never show their true feelings. They only show other people a friendly front and you don't get to see or hear what they are really thinking. In other words, the 'beauty from all angles' is considered to be fake.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the negative context of the word :)